# horizontally scrollable grid co-exists with a fixed right column programmatically in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, programmatically-created

> I have been trying to think of a way to make a table (UICollectionView) with a fixed last column and the rest of the table with a horizontal overflow.

I am using swift ios. can some help here?

I used UICollectionView to scrolling in one direction but I am not able to fix right column .[image]

Comment: you want to fix month column?

Comment: Actually , I want to fix last column. you can take this image an example. think the month column is at most right of table

Comment: You can use this cocoa control library to present above data with fixed columns https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView

Comment: In Image as it is col3??

Comment: [Check this tutorial](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/sticky-grid-collection-view/). It will help you out.

Comment: Yes. col3 should be fix and rest of table can scroll horizontally.

Comment: @Animesh Thanks for tutorial, But It is scrolling in vertical direction. I am looking for 

https://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns 

this solution in swift programmatically .

Comment: @CodeChanger I don't want to use other libraries .